# Else statement is executing along with if statement

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer learning Python 3.4.3.  I am writing a program which tokenizes a string representing a mathematical formula, or turning the string into a list.

I am using a series of if / elif / else statements to accomplish this.  My code for this function is as follows:

```
def positive_or_add(usr_string, place):
    """ Determines if a + or - is intended to be a add /subtract or positive
    or negative.  Takes a string (usr_string) and an integer (place) to
    determine the place in the string.  Returns true for an operator, or
    negative for pos/neg
    (string) -> bool
    >>> '3 + 5 +(-4)
    Fales
    """
    #munover the place setting prior to the +/- operator
    place -= 1
    #munover left through the white space to determine what preceeded
    while usr_string[place] == ' ':
        place -= 1
    if usr_string[place].isdigit() or usr_string[place] == ')':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def tokenize(usr_string):
    """
    (str) -> list
    Takes a string, and tokenizes it.  Basically turning the string
    representing a mathimatical formual and making it into a list, eliminating
    the white spaces
    >>> '3 + 5 + (-4)
    [3, +, 5, +, (, -4, )]
    """
    token_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(usr_string):
#Add values to the list that arent white space, + or -
        if usr_string[i] != ' ' and usr_string[i] != '+' and usr_string[i] != '-':
            token_list.append(usr_string[i])
            i += 1
        elif usr_string[i] == '+' or usr_string[i] == '-':
#Determine if that + or - is an operator or pos / neg
            sign = positive_or_add(usr_string, i)
            if sign == True: #Operator
                token_list.append(usr_string[i])
                i += 1
            elif sign == False: #pos / neg
                token_list.append(usr_string[i] + usr_string[i + 1])
                i += 2
        elif usr_string == ' ':
            continue
        else:
            print('something messed up')
            i += 1
    return token_list

#Test
print(tokenize('3 + 5 + (-4)'))
```

My problem is that my else statement is always executing, along with the if / elif statements.  I basically get the 'something messed up' line multiple times, followed by my generated list tonek_list.

When I try to erase the else statement the program basically gives me a blank line, and nothing happens.

I am guessing I am just not seeing something here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please paste positive_or_add function here

Comment: Your input string contains parens, the tokenizer doesn't seem to handle parens.

Comment: I apologize, I am not sure what a Parens is (not there yet I guess....)

Comment: Parens is just short for parentheses. Before you updated, the `(` and `)` had no obvious handler; having pasted, the handling code for them seems very fragile and may not work properly depending on whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have the fixed code:

```
def tokenize(usr_string):
    """
    (str) -> list
    Takes a string, and tokenizes it.  Basically turning the string
    representing a mathimatical formual and making it into a list, eliminating
    the white spaces
    >>> '3 + 5 + (-4)
    [3, +, 5, +, (, -4, )]
    """
    token_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(usr_string):
#Add values to the list that arent white space, + or -
        if usr_string[i] != ' ' and usr_string[i] != '+' and usr_string[i] != '-':
            token_list.append(usr_string[i])
            i += 1
        elif usr_string[i] == '+' or usr_string[i] == '-':
#Determine if that + or - is an operator or pos / neg
            sign = positive_or_add(usr_string, i)
            if sign == True: #Operator
                token_list.append(usr_string[i])
                i += 1
            elif sign == False: #pos / neg
                token_list.append(usr_string[i] + usr_string[i + 1])
                i += 2
        elif usr_string[i] == ' ':
            i += 1
            continue
        else:
            print('something messed up')
            i += 1
    return token_list
```

**Fixed:**

 - `sr_string[i]` instead of `sr_string` (line 26)

 - Needed an indent of `i += 1` before `continue`, otherwise infinite loop

Comment: My infinite loop was caused by not including i += 1 on the elif usr_string[i] == ' ' statement for anyone that is interested.

Comment: True, and the code will work after that is fixed @DntMesArnd. Just realized that right now when looking at it

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate problem almost *certainly* has to do with this line here:

```
elif usr_string == ' ':
```

Every other check is being performed on `usr_string[i]` so I'm not sure exactly what prompted you to check the *entire* string for that particular case. What it means is that, whenever you find a space in the input string (and the whole string isn't just a single space), it will drop through to your "something amiss" case.

In addition, that's the only case where you're not incrementing the index variable `i` so the first space you find (once you've fixed that first issue) will put you into an infinite loop.

I think you'll find things will go a lot smoother if you change it to:

```
elif usr_string[i] == ' ':
    i += 1
```

---

Even once *both* those issues are fixed, it appears that you have no code to correctly handle the parentheses `(` and `)`. For now, I'd suggest taking them out of the input string so as to test a more basic expression but you'll probably need to handle them at some point.

Comment: Additionally, for all but the top level test, it seems to ignore the possibility of whitespace, and only handle parens properly when there is no whitespace. Haven't checked it in detail, the code is... hard to follow.

Comment: That certainly solved the problem of the else statement.  Thanks!  Was just a typing error.   Now when I run the code I only get a blank line.

Comment: My goal was to no include white space in the resulting list.  Once I get it running I am thinking I need to go through it and see if there is a better way...

Comment: @DntMesArnd, well, that would be a *different* problem, worthy of another question, I'd imagine. *This* problem (execution of the `else` block) is solved as far as I can see.

Comment: My problem with the infinite loop was a result of not including the statement i += 1 in my elif usr_list == ' ' loop.  Thanks for the help everyone